# Tango with Django - Chapter 8 - Exercise

Tags: python, html, django, url

I need some help getting the add_page function to work properly.  I am very new to HTML and even newer to Django.  The chapter I am working on can be found here: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/forms.html.  Currently my relevent files look like this:

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Page, Category

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the category name.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)


class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page.")
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Page

        # What fields do we want to include in our form?
        # This way we don't need every field in the model present.
        # Some fields may allow NULL values, so we may not want to include them...
        # Here, we are hiding the foreign key.
        # we can either exclude the category field from the form,
        exclude = ('category',)
        #or specify the fields to include (i.e. not include the category field)
        #fields = ('title', 'url', 'views')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')

        # If url is not empty and doesn't start with 'http://', prepend 'http://'.
        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

        return cleaned_data
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rango.models import Category, Page
from rango.forms import CategoryForm, PageForm

def index(request):
    # Query the database for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
    # Order the categories by no. likes in descending order.
    # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.
    # Place the list in our context_dict dictionary which will be passed to the template engine.
    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-view')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list,
                    'pages': page_list}

    # Render the response and send it back!
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)

def category(request, category_name_slug):

    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}

    try:
        # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        context_dict['category_name'] = category.name
        context_dict['category_name_slug'] = category_name_slug

        # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
        # Note that filter returns >= 1 model instance.
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
        pass

    # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    print context_dict
    return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)

def add_category(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = CategoryForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'rango/add_category.html', {'form': form})

def add_page(request, category_name_slug):

    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
                cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                # probably better to use a redirect here.
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'form':form, 'category': cat}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
#        url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
        url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name='add_category'), 
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
        url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),)
```

I think this ^ is where I am encountering the issue.  I manage to get to the "add a page" screen, but when I try to submit something, I receive an error that states I am only supplying 1 argument and add_page() requires 2.  I think I may need an additional url that is similar to the "add_category" URL, but that must mean by other URL is pointing to the wrong place?

category.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>{{ category_name }}</h1>
        {% if category %}
            {% if pages %}
            <ul>
                {% for page in pages %}
                <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

            {% else %}
                <strong>No pages currently in category.</strong>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">Add a New Page</a></li>
        {% else %}
            The specified category {{ category_name }} does not exist!
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

add_page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add a Page</h1>

        <form id="page_form" method="post" action="/rango/add_page/">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post the add_page.html template, and remove the irrelevant category.html and all the views except add_page.

Comment: I thought category.html was relevant because I had made changes to it.  I've added the add_page.html

Comment: You've got the form posting to /rango/add_page/, rather than /category/whatever/add_page/, so you must have another urls.py entry that responds to that: where? can you post it?

Comment: I understand that.  What I don't understand is where I want that url to take me.  Should I tell the button to bring me to /category/whatever/add_page/ like they insinuate in the answer below?  Wouldn't that just bring me in a circle?

Comment: No, because your view does something different if you POST to it: it processes the form and creates a new page.

Comment: I changed the line to: 
<form id="page_form" method="post" action="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">

...and then I receive the error "The current URL, rango/category//add_page/, didn't match any of these."  So it doesn't seem to populate the field.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to update the context_dict in views.py to include category_name_slug

Answer (score 2):

I edited the add_page function to include category_name_slug:

```
def add_page(request, category_name_slug):

    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
                cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                # probably better to use a redirect here.
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    # made the change here
    context_dict = {'form':form, 'category': cat, 'category_name_slug': category_name_slug}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

Then I edited the add_page.html to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add a Page</h1>

        <form id="page_form" method="post" action="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The modifications to the `add_page.html` template are not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont wanna edit your views.py

just doit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Add a Page</h1>

        <form id="page_form" method="post" action="/rango/category/{{ category }}/add_page/">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

but i have problem to it still cannot be save on database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your add page link change it to :

```
    <a href = "add_page/">Add Page</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).